# Passing MySQL date range query in Delphi using UniQuery with variable string date values gives me returns NULL

Tags: mysql, delphi

I am passing MySQL query using UniQuery in Delphi and it is returing NULL.

I already change the date format in the property of my TDBDateTimeEditEh to match with mysql format yyyy-mm-dd and pass this to my string variable at runtime.

Here's my code:

```
    procedure TfrmPayroll.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      DateRangeQry, StartDate, EndDate : string;
    begin
      StartDate := dthStart.Text;
      EndDate := dthEnd.Text;
      DateRangeQry := 'SELECT * FROM mytimesheet WHERE Date >= '+ StartDate +' AND date <= '+ EndDate +'';

    //ShowMessage(StartDate +' to '+ EndDate); // result yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd

      with dm_u.dmPayroll do
        begin
          uqMyTimesheet.SQL.Clear;
          uqMyTimesheet.sql.Text := DateRangeQry;
          uqMyTimesheet.ExecSQL;
          cdsMyTimesheet.Refresh;
        end;
    end;
```

I did check the value in the showmessage and it is matching the date format in mysql.

I supposed my codes about would generate range of records from the database within the date range specified but no avail.

I will appreciate any help from you guys.

Updates:

[image]

Comment: 1. Stop using concatenated strings for your queries (lookup SQL injection)
2. Use parameters (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37129888/800214) for example
3. all your problems are solved...

Comment: 4. `uqMyTimesheet.SQL.Clear;` is pointless. Setter of property `Text` calls `Clear` within `BeginUpdate` .. `EndUpdate` block.

Answer (score 3):

Using parameters instead of OLD concatenated queries style, is better, clear and it works ever!
Try this code.

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
      DateRangeQry, StartDate, EndDate : string;
begin

      StartDate:='01/01/2019';
      EndDate:='01/01/2020';

      DateRangeQry:='SELECT * FROM mytimesheet WHERE Date >= :StartDate AND date <= :EndDate';
      uqMyTimesheet.SQL.Text:=DateRangeQry;
      uqMyTimesheet.ParamByName('StartDate').AsDate := StrToDate(StartDate);
      uqMyTimesheet.ParamByName('EndDate').AsDate := StrToDate(EndDate);
      uqMyTimesheet.Open;



end;
```

Another approach when you have different date formats is convert date to string

```
  StartDate:='2019-01-01';
  EndDate:='2020-01-01';

  DateRangeQry:='SELECT * FROM mytimesheet WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Date, ''%Y-%m-%d'') between :StartDate AND :EndDate';
  UniQuery1.SQL.Text:=DateRangeQry;
  UniQuery1.ParamByName('StartDate').AsString := (StartDate);
  UniQuery1.ParamByName('EndDate').AsString := (EndDate);
  UniQuery1.Open;
```

Comment: I appreciate the share of doing this better. I tried your code but I am not getting any response, no error message even. So, I tried to change the assigned variable exactly the same format with database '2019-01-01' and I am getting the error instead as —  '2019-01-01' it is not a valid date. I've been reading date format issues but it is getting me nowhere. I know the date is a bit complicated, perhaps for me only. Need some more help here. Thanks.

Comment: Please, share a stamp of dataset, then "mytimesheet" fields type also, to better understand where the error is

Comment: I have updated my query above. Hope these are the ones you were looking for. Otherwise, let me know.

Comment: I need just a stamp of a recordset result from "SELECT DATE FROM mytimesheet LIMIT 10"

Comment: Uploaded.. please check again above.

Comment: I've just posted another approach. Let me know please.

Comment: Why not declare StartDate and EndDate as `TDate`?  Then, instead of trying to force fit the format, use the first example above, passing the DATE to the parameter. Also, really bad form to have a column named "Date".  If you control that, label it something like "tsDate".

Comment: Make the query use `TParam.AsDate` and then wrap the query in a function that takes `TDate` values as input. That way, the code is agnostic to the formatting that the DB uses for date values. Make the caller decide how best to produce valid `TDate` values to pass in however it wants. For instance, by using a `TDateTimePicker` instead of a text input like `TDBDateTimeEditEh`.  Or using `EncodeDate()` instead of `StrToDate('<literal>')`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you give a quick code of what your saying here. It is actually new to me. I tried but I am getting nowhere with the function.

Comment: @Mel see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameterized query instead, using `TDate` instead of `string` for the parameter values, eg:

```pascal
procedure TfrmPayroll.QueryTimeSheet(StartDate, EndDate: TDate);
begin
  //ShowMessage(DateToStr(StartDate) + ' to ' + DateToStr(EndDate)); // result yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd
  with dm_u.dmPayroll do
  begin
    uqMyTimesheet.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM mytimesheet WHERE Date >= :PStartDate AND date <= :PEndDate';
    uqMyTimesheet.ParamByName('PStartDate').AsDate := StartDate;
    uqMyTimesheet.ParamByName('PEndDate').AsDate := EndDate;
    uqMyTimesheet.ExecSQL;
    cdsMyTimesheet.Refresh;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmPayroll.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  QueryTimeSheet(dthStart.Value, dthEnd.Value);
end;
```

Comment: Wow! @RemyLebeau Works like a charm! Thank you so much! Got it perfectly and additional knowledge. However, I cannot vote for you. I'll vote on this little later when I have more points.